# phpass different results in local and host

Tags: codeigniter, phpass

I just put my project from localhost to my host and using the same (phpass) function I receive different results and the length of the returned string is also different. (and everything works on localhost.)

Here's the result:

Input: 12345

```
host:$2a$08$t5joFUIbEThylj/IyUVy7.WzMZm8fmKjsy0kZc/YxgqzkbYQWnlre
localhost: $P$9QiKVfJzpRzoToBCJg8FeaDIfcAJJ61
```

I was wondering what the problem might be.
thanks for all suggest and answer.

Comment: Using portable hashes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [phpass returns different results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897576/phpass-returns-different-results)

Comment: yes, I use portable hashes.

Comment: is that related with php version the server use?