# Issue to match pHpass generated hashed passwords

Tags: php, hash, phpass

I add new user to database and hash user password using pHpass. On this point I face weird problem.

If I create/hash the password '123' on `http://localhost/add.php` and check the password using pHpass's CheckPassword method on the same page it will say that password is good. But if I check the previously created hash password, created on *http://localhost/add.php*, on `http://localhost/login.php`, it says the password is invalid. What is this?

My pHpass 3.0 (*Downloaded from: http://www.openwall.com/phpass/*) settings are

```
Iteration Count = 8
Portable Hashes = FALSE
```

I also tried it with Portable `Hashes = TRUE` but same results. So how on earth any body will be able to match password if anybody faces this situation.

---

Here is how I did all.

1. On add.php I used *pHpass* method `HashPassword` to hash incoming user password from POST and saved it to database.
2. On login.php I used *pHpass* method `CheckPassword` with two parameters, 1st unhashed user password and 2nd hashed password saved in the database against user name; just as *pHpass* mentioned in `test.php` file downloaded from **http://www.openwall.com/phpass/**

Help meeee !

Comment: i hope this will help u @Adnan.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343611/portable-phpass-password-hashes-should-i-use-them

Comment: I read @devpro it did not helped me ... Andrew answer is good but still I don't know why my created password on add.php is not working on login.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes if you stored password in hash value at add time than whenever you need to login from login.php than you will convert your password value into hash firstly and than compare it with your stored value and it will works.

Comment: Not sure but please check this link : 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

hope it will help you.